# Why this two datasets don't match?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a postGIS database in SRS 4326 (WGS84) with several Europe layers working well, but when I load a shapefile projected to the same SRS with QGIS, the layers don't match.

To explain it better I've made two screenshots:
The pink one are the German postcodes from my postGIS database, that are matching with all the rest of my data
[image]

The second one, green polygons, are German postcodes too, but from a shapefile.
Both of them are in WGS84 (EPSG:4326, I've reprojected it with QGIS, and shows it in layer propperties). I've marked the coordinates below, to see that the it seems that the second one's coordinates are not correct.

[image]

Some Idea that how could I fix the green dataset to overlap with the rest? (pink)
The source of the green dataset is this URL: http://arnulf.us/PLZ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second dataset is definitely not WGS84. The East coordinate is negative, which is not possible for Germany.

The dataset comes without a .prj file, so you have to **assign** EPSG:4326 with `Set CRS for Layer`. Reprojecting is wrong, if you do not have the correct starting CRS.

This is my import of the shapefile:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've copied the .prj file from the first to the second one and renamed it, and now it overlaps perfectly.